# r description file title with special characters

Tags: r

Is it possible to use superscripts in the DESCRIPTION file when creating an R package? I tried in the Title statement (as in .rd files):

```
Title: \eqn{x^2}-Test
```

and as in Latex code:

```
Title: $x^2$-Test
```

and with unicode:

```
Title: x\U00B2-Test
```

But nothing worked.

Thanks for help, Tobi

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in "Creating R packages", pages 4 and 7: The DESCRIPTION file should be entirely written in ASCII code. Otherwise, an 'Encoding' field has to be added to the DESCRIPTION file. It is recommended not to use encoding because this would make the package less portable. Whatever that means...

I will omit the superscript in the title. It does not look very nice but it seems that this will reduce problems...

Comment: "Portable" means installable across multiple platforms.

Comment: I found this helpful. For future reference, the document where @Tobi found the answer can be found here: https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2016-01-02/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file